# Im always getting Call to a member function fetchAll() on boolean in

Tags: php, ms-access, pdo

I'm always getting Call to a member function `fetchAll()` on boolean in, I'm using Microsoft Access I'm new at PDO so I don't know if I do it right

My Error:

> Fatal error
> : Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\newtimein_timeout\filter.php:46 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\newtimein_timeout\filter.php
> on line
> 46

```php
<?php
    $dbName = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\newtimein_timeout\att2000.mdb';
    if (!file_exists($dbName)) {
    die("Could not find database file.");
    }
    $connect = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; Server=localhost; 
    Port=3306; DBQ=$dbName; Uid=; Pwd=;");
    $output = ''; 
    $query = "select a.USERID, a.CHECKTIME, a.CHECKTYPE, b.Name, 
    b.Badgenumber,date_format(a.CHECKTIME, '%Y-%m-%d') as Date,
      (CASE
            WHEN date_format(c.CHECKTIME, '%h:%i:%s') IS NULL THEN '--:--:--'
            ELSE date_format(c.CHECKTIME, '%h:%i:%s')
        END) as start_time, 
        (CASE
            WHEN date_format(d.CHECKTIME, '%h:%i:%s') IS NULL THEN '--:--:--'
            ELSE date_format(d.CHECKTIME, '%h:%i:%s')
        END) as break_out,
        (CASE
            WHEN date_format(e.CHECKTIME, '%h:%i:%s') IS NULL THEN '--:--:--'
            ELSE date_format(e.CHECKTIME, '%h:%i:%s')
        END) as break_in,
        (CASE
            WHEN date_format(f.CHECKTIME, '%h:%i:%s') IS NULL THEN '--:--:--'
            ELSE date_format(f.CHECKTIME, '%h:%i:%s')
        END) as end_time 
      from checkinout a
      left join (select USERID, CHECKTIME from checkinout where CHECKTYPE='I') c
      ON a.USERID=c.USERID AND date_format(a.CHECKTIME, '%Y-%m-%d')=date_format(c.CHECKTIME, '%Y-%m-%d')
      left join (select USERID, CHECKTIME from checkinout where CHECKTYPE='0') d
      ON a.USERID=d.USERID AND date_format(a.CHECKTIME, '%Y-%m-%d')=date_format(d.CHECKTIME, '%Y-%m-%d')
      left join (select USERID, CHECKTIME from checkinout where CHECKTYPE='1') e
      ON a.USERID=e.USERID AND date_format(a.CHECKTIME, '%Y-%m-%d')=date_format(e.CHECKTIME, '%Y-%m-%d')
      left join (select USERID, CHECKTIME from checkinout where CHECKTYPE='O') f
      ON a.USERID=f.USERID AND date_format(a.CHECKTIME, '%Y-%m-%d')=date_format(f.CHECKTIME, '%Y-%m-%d')
      left join userinfo b 
      ON a.USERID=b.USERID
      WHERE a.USERID > 0";
          if(!empty($_POST["name"])){
            $query .= " AND b.Name like '%".$_POST["name"]."%' "; 
          } 
          if(!empty($_POST["from_date"]) && (!empty($_POST["to_date"])) ) {
            $query .= " AND date_format(a.CHECKTIME, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '".$_POST["from_date"]."' AND '".$_POST["to_date"]."' ";
          }
      $query .= " GROUP BY Date";

      $result = $connect->query($query);
      if ($row = $result->fetchAll()){
          echo '<div style="font-size:18px;" class="col-sm-12"><b>ID NUMBER:</b>&nbsp;' . $row['Name'] . '</div>';
          echo '<div style="font-size:18px;" class="col-sm-12"><b>EMPLOYEE NAME:</b>&nbsp;' . $row['Badgenumber'] . '</div>';
      }
      $output .= '  
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                      <thead class="thead-dark">
                          <tr>
                              <th style="width:220px">Date</th>
                              <th>Time In</th>
                              <th>Break Out</th>
                              <th>Break In</th>
                              <th>Time Out</th>
                          </tr>
                      </thead>
      ';  

      if($result->fetchColumn() > 0)  
      {  
           while($row = $result->fetchAll())  
           {  
                $date=date_create($row['CHECKTIME']);
                $dDate = date_format($date,"M d, Y (D)");

                $output .= ' 
                        <tr>
                              <td>'. $dDate .'</td>
                              <td>'. $start_time .'</td>
                              <td>'. $break_out .'</td>
                              <td>'. $break_in .'</td>
                              <td>'. $end_time .'</td>
                        </tr>
                    ';
           }  
      }  
      else  
      {  
           $output .= '  
                <tr>  
                     <td colspan="5">No Data Found</td>  
                </tr>  
           ';  
      }  
      $output .= '</table>';  
      echo $output;  
?>
```

Comment: If Access is supposed to process that SQL, it can't. Access SQL cannot handle CASE structure. And I am not sure about the multiple JOIN structure. Access is picky about parentheses.

Comment: Thank you for a huge help for me. Maybe I should import Access SQL to Mysql. Again thank you